# Sort multidimensional array/slice

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, go, slice

I have created a multidimensional array (slice) in Go as follows:

```
var distancematrix [5][5]int
```

So it is a 5*5 array/slice.
Now I am inserting values into this slice such that at a point:

```
distancematrix :  [[0 154 12 35 138] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Now, I want to sort this array in ascending order, e.g.:

```
sorteddistancematrix :  [[0 12 35  138 154] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I tried `sort.Ints(distancematrix[0])` but it throws an error saying:

```
cannot use distancematrix[0] (type [5]int) as type []int in argument to sort.Ints
```

Basically, **I want to fetch the smallest non-zero value in the array**. 
How can I sort this array to achieve this?

Comment: You are mixing the term array and slice throughout your question. I would recommend reading [this article](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) for some clarification.

Comment: Fetching the smallest non-zero value does not require sorting the array, in fact  it'll be rather wasteful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the smallest non-zero element, you don't need to sort it. Sorting an array or slice is relatively a costly operation - compared to just getting the smallest non-zero element.

Generally to get the smallest non-zero element, just loop over the values, and look for the value that fits you best. If you find a better one (in your example a smaller non-zero), keep that and continue.

Example implementation:

```
func smallestNonZero(s []int) (n int) {
    for _, v := range s {
        if v != 0 && (v < n || n == 0) {
            n = v
        }
    }
    return
}
```

**Note:** This function will return `0` if and only if the passed slice does not contain any non-zero element (that is, it's either full of `0`s or it's empty or it's `nil`). This function also works properly if the slice (also) contains negative numbers.

If you have an array and not a slice, simply slice the array (which results in a slice) and so you can pass it to the function above.

Using it:

```
fmt.Println(smallestNonZero([]int{5, 3, 1, 4}))
fmt.Println(smallestNonZero([]int{0, 3, 5, 8, 0, 2, 9}))
arr := [5]int{0, 154, 12, 35, 138}
fmt.Println(smallestNonZero(arr[:]))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/zQ0-XQP8Fq)):

```
1
2
12
```

Comment: +1 for the key points: 1. the array doesn't need to be sorted to find the smallest element, and 2. that sorting arrays/slices is typically a much more expensive operation than a one pass search.

Comment: Thanks a lot icza :) 
That resolves my query. 
Also, canyou tell me how can I get the index of the smallest positive number ? 
Like I tried this : 
func smallestNonZeroIndex(s []int) (n int) {
 var i int
 for i, v := range s {
  if v > 0 && (v < n || n == 0) {
   n = v
   i++
  }
 }
 return i
}
but it returns 0 always. 
Thanks in advance ..

Comment: @fnaticRCggwp If you use `for range`, you shouldn't increment the loop variable `i` as it is incremented automatically/internally. Just copy my code from the answer.

Comment: @ICZA I need the INDEX of the SMALLLEST POSITIVE NUMBER. 

How can I get that using FOR LOOP ?

Answer (score 2):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)
>
> Slice expressions construct a substring or slice from a string, array,
>   pointer to array, or slice. There are two variants: a simple form that
>   specifies a low and high bound, and a full form that also specifies a
>   bound on the capacity.
>
> Simple slice expressions
>
> For a string, array, pointer to array, or slice a, the primary
>   expression
>
> ```
> a[low : high]
> ```
>
> constructs a substring or slice. The indices low and high select which
>   elements of operand a appear in the result. The result has indices
>   starting at 0 and length equal to high - low. After slicing the array
>   a
>
> ```
> a := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> s := a[1:4]
> ```
>
> the slice s has type []int, length 3, capacity 4, and elements
>
> ```
> s[0] == 2
> s[1] == 3
> s[2] == 4
> ```
>
> For convenience, any of the indices may be omitted. A missing low
>   index defaults to zero; a missing high index defaults to the length of
>   the sliced operand:
>
> ```
> a[2:]  // same as a[2 : len(a)]
> a[:3]  // same as a[0 : 3]
> a[:]   // same as a[0 : len(a)]
> ```
>
> If a is a pointer to an array, a[low : high] is shorthand for (*a)[low
>   : high].

To convert type `[5]int` to type `[]int`, slice the array. For example,

```
package main

import "sort"

func main() {
    var distancematrix [5][5]int
    sort.Ints(distancematrix[0][:])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var distancematrix [5][5]int, will create multidimensional array slice of 5 * 5 int. And when you try to access distancematrix[0], it returns int array slice of type [5]int. Where as sort.Ints expects type []int.

Here below I have declared distancematrix of type [][] and hence distancematrix[0] returns slice array of type []int.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    distancematrix := [][]int{{0, 154, 12, 35, 138}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
    sort.Ints(distancematrix[0])
    fmt.Println(distancematrix[0])
}
```